# How close can one get to Eldborg with public transportation?

Tags: public-transport, hiking, iceland

[Eldborg](http://www.west.is/en/west/place/eldborg-crater) is a volcanic crater in Western Iceland.
Is it possible to reach the crater by public transportation? Or what is the closest one can get using public transportation (probably bus)?

Comment: A prompt return is not necessary. Could be walking to Borgarnes for all I care.

Comment: Combining the two comments I conclude that a passing bus (probably Straeto bus 58) is happy to drop you off at the nearest point (a few K from the volcano). If somebody turns this into an answer I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: You may want to look into [Kerið](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keri%C3%B0) - it's a small implosion crater that's literally right next to a road. From what I can tell from the South Iceland map on [straeto.is](http://www.straeto.is/english/plan-your-journey/schedules-and-maps), Lines 72 and 73 service Borg í Grímsnesi which would be very close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Website you mentioned in the question, covers [public transportation](http://www.west.is/en/travel/transportation/public-transportation#bigMapTop). Also, bus operator has a handy [plan your journey](http://s.straeto.is/journeyplanner/enterJourneyPlan.do?hss=fM70Q177396320) tool.

What you probably want to search, is the route from [Reykjavík to Stykkishólmur](http://s.straeto.is/journeyplanner/showJourneyDetailsPage.do?rid=1438189859614&hss=SP5ET177396116). You will have to switch buses at Borgarnes (from no. 57 to no. 58). Make sure the driver will drop you off where you want though. You can also try hitchhiking from Borgarnes. In the summer there are a lot of tourists and Snaefellsnes peninsula is quite popular destination.

Also, make sure to be dropped off at the road to the farm south of Eldborg (Snorrastadir) and take an "official" trail from there. As far as I recall, there is a fence around the crater area (it's nature's reserve I think) and the terrain around it is quite difficult. You can also sleep at this farm if need be - there is camping site, showers, kitchen etc.

EDIT: I highly recommend to use this instead of Google maps, it is just much better (you can see the trails etc.): [Ja.is maps](http://en.ja.is/kort/?type=map)

Comment: Thank you. Great answer. I wouldn't dream of using Google Maps for anything serious. I have six maps from the Mál og Menning 1:100.000 series. That should be enough to keep me busy for a while.

Comment: Speaking of Iceland maps: The [National Land Survey of Iceland](http://www.lmi.is/en/) offers the raw, highly detailed GIS vector datasets for download at [IS 50V](http://www.lmi.is/en/stafraen-gogn/is-50v-nytt/) (after registration). Using a GIS application like [QGIS](http://qgis.org/) and a bit of time you can use these datasets to build your own maps. There's also web maps available that are based on these datasets: [English](http://atlas.lmi.is/kortasja_en/) | [Icelandic](http://atlas.lmi.is/kortasja/).